# Uploadify does not work in chrome

Tags: jquery, file-upload, uploadify, swfupload

Fileopen window does not open in chrome it works fine in firefox

Here is the [link](http://shop2build.com/fawaaz/product/tractor-emulsion-smooth-wall-finish-10-lts-2/)